# If $u_{n+1} = u_n^2 - u_n + 1$ and $u_0=a>1$, show that $\sum\frac{1}{u_n} \rightarrow \frac{1}{a-1}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

If $(u_n)\in\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N},u_{n+1} = u_n^2 - u_n + 1$ and $u_0=a>1$, show that $\sum\dfrac{1}{u_n} \rightarrow \dfrac{1}{a-1}$.

I don't even know how to prove that the series converges

Comment: At first glance, this could be related to the geometric series, in which $u_n=-a^{-n}$

Comment: What's $(u_n)\in\Bbb R^{\Bbb N}$ supposed to denote?

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt sequences of real numbers

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The key observation, which kills theproblem quite instantly, is the following: for every $n$ it holds the relation $$\frac{1}{u_n} = \frac{1}{u_n - 1} - \frac{1}{u_{n + 1} - 1}$$ Indeed we have $$\frac{1}{u_n - 1} - \frac{1}{u_{n + 1} - 1} = \frac{1}{u_n - 1} - \frac{1}{u_n(u_n - 1)} = \frac{u_n - 1}{u_n(u_n - 1)} = \frac{1}{u_n}$$
Hence we have a telescopic sum: $$\sum_{n = 0}^{N} \frac{1}{u_n} = \sum_{n = 0}^N \left(\frac{1}{u_n - 1} - \frac{1}{u_{n + 1} - 1}\right) = \\ = \left(\frac{1}{u_0 - 1} - \frac{1}{u_1 - 1}\right) + \left(\frac{1}{u_1 - 1} - \frac{1}{u_2 - 1}\right) + \cdots + \left(\frac{1}{u_N - 1} - \frac{1}{u_{N + 1} - 1}\right) = \\ = \frac{1}{a - 1} + \frac{1}{u_{N + 1} - 1}$$ Now it is pretty easy to prove that $\displaystyle \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} u_n = \infty$ and thus $$\lim_{N \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{n = 0}^N \frac{1}{u_i} = \lim_{N \rightarrow \infty} \left(\frac{1}{a - 1} + \frac{1}{u_{N + 1} - 1}\right) = \frac{1}{a - 1}$$

So the series converges to $\dfrac{1}{a - 1}$.

Comment: Out of curiosity, how did you come up with $\frac{1}{u_n} = \frac{1}{u_n - 1} - \frac{1}{u_{n + 1} - 1}$ ?

Comment: @GabrielRomon If you think the series is telescoping, there's really no other choice other than to guess $\frac 1{u_n} = \frac 1{u_n-1} - \text{something}$, given that $a=u_0$. The telescope is harder to guess when given a specific value for $a$, especially if $a=2$.

Comment: @grand_chat sure thing, thanks for your insight.

Comment: Actually I got there in a more straightforward way. I thought that, assuming the thesis true, the same should happen when we replace $a_0$ with $a_1$. In other words it should hold not only $\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{u_n} = \frac{1}{u_0 - 1}$, but also $\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{u_n} = \frac{1}{u_1 - 1}$. Now subtracting these we get $\frac{1}{u_0} = \frac{1}{u_0 - 1} - \frac{1}{u_1 - 1}$, and one can check that this holds as an identity. This way I got the idea for the magic relation.

Answer (score 0):

Going the other way,
if
$\dfrac1{u_n}
=\dfrac1{u_n-a}-\dfrac1{u_{n+1}-a}
$,
so that
$\sum\dfrac1{u_n}$
converges via telescoping,
then,
simplifying,
$u_n^2-au_n+a^2
=au_{n+1}
$.

This is the case
$a=1$.

Of course the seemingly
more general case
reduces to the case
$a=1$
by replacing $u_n$
by
$\dfrac{u_n}{a}
$.

Comment: :-/ 5 hours behind cip999's answer, and doesn't seem to be an improvement over it.

Comment: I just wanted to see if it could be generalized. Turns out nothing interesting happens.